# Error trying to 'group ' in mongoose with '$expr' and find()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to group some results by the `movieId` feild.

And I keep getting an error.

Here is the code:

```
   router.get("/best-sellers2", (req, res) => {
    Show.find({
        '$expr': {
            $group: {
                _id: '$_MovieId',
                count: { $sum: 1 }
            }
        }
    }, {}).then(shows => {
        console.log('got all shows of a specific movie');
        console.log(shows);
        res.json(shows);
    });
});
```

Here is the Error:

```
(node:6524) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$group'

(node:6524) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Anybody knows what is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: You can use [**aggregation pipeline operators**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) with `$expr` not [**aggregation pipeline stages**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

Answer (score 1):

Simple aggregation will work:

```
Show.aggregate([{
  "$match" : {
    "movieId": ObjectId("5b649c81e361853956b35900"),
  }
},{
  $group: { 
    "_id" : "$movieId",
    "count" : {"$sum": 1}
  }
}]);
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> {
>   "_id" : ObjectId("5b649c81e361853956b35900"),
>   "count" : 2.0
> }
> ```

Hope this may help you.

Let me know if you need a more specific query.

And if so then please add some more code into your question to understand what is your data and what should be your output.